# How to configure multiple schema in the same datasource in Tomcat?

Tags: java, database, tomcat

My application uses multiple schemas in a database (userName and password connecting to the database is same for all schema). Right now am configuring the datasource by providing resouces tag as mentioned below in **tomcat server.xml**

```
<Resource name="jdbc/datasource" auth="Container" 
      type="ConnectionPoolDataSource"
      scope="Shareable" url="jdbc_url"
      factory="JDBCObjectFactory"
      driverClassName="JDBCDriver"
      serverName="myserver.com"
      libraries="Schema1"
      userName="username" pwd="password"
      secure="false"
      prompt="false"/>
```

How can I modify it to accommodate multiple schema. My application uses DB2 database

[Tomcat JDBC connection pool for different schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34436686/tomcat-jdbc-connection-pool-for-different-schema) this provides a solution to prefix tables with schema name in each query but i want it to be configured in server.xml

**Note:** Tried to provide comma separated values in libraries (libraries="Schema1,Schema2") but tables from schema2 were not accessible in my application.